# UnitTest a LibGDX game

Tags: java, junit, libgdx

I've a very big problem: I can't run Unit Tests because of NullPointerException. I'll be more clear:

```
private Character c;
   private Sprite s;
   private Gioco1 g;
   private HeadlessApplicationConfiguration cfg;
   HeadlessApplication app;
   @Before
   public  void setUp() throws Exception {
      this.cfg = new HeadlessApplicationConfiguration();
      this.g= new Gioco1();
      this.app =new HeadlessApplication(g, cfg);
   }

   @Test
   public void testLeft(){      

      this.c=g.getPacman();
      c.left();
      assertEquals(c.getSprite().getX(),c.getSprite().getX()-2,0f);

}
```

The problem is that g.getPacman() returns an object of type Character (it's a class of mine) that is always NULL. Even if I try to istantiate a new Character with:

```
c = new Character("res/pacman.png");
```

it does not work. Here's the constructor of Character:

```
public Character(String img) {
      super(img);
      right=true;
      left=false;
      down=false;
      up=false;   
      Sprite=new Sprite(this);
   }
```

It gives a NullPointerException on super(img) where super is the constructor of Texture (Character extends Texture). How is this possible? It's like the test class does not recognize the internal path "res/pacman.png".

I've no idea on how do Unit Tests on this application.

May you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How if pacman.png moved to folder assets??

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I don't have assets folder, only res . But I understand what you're trying to tell me...it's something with Gdx.files.internal() , right?

Comment: May you be more explicative?

Comment: this folder usually at project yourgame-android or yourgame-desktop. take all assets for your game in this folder. (as fas as I know)

Comment: yups.. I usually use that command..

Comment: I don't have assets folder. Here it is my folder structure: http://it.tinypic.com/r/2rxtis3/8

Comment: Your assets folder is at android project.

Comment: How are you running your Unit Tests?  And what is the complete backtrace of the exception you are seeing?  (I suspect you are running Libgdx in a way that does not completely initialize it.)

Comment: Trace: http://pastebin.com/Aq5uUBQ3

I just create the class CharacterTest as I showed you. :)

Comment: Did you initialize your libgdx project with gdx-setup?

Comment: Nope, I hate gradle. Too much complexity for a simple project.

Comment: Then i bet you initialized it not properly. Try to initialize it with Gradle (nothing scary).